# Which popular libraries for a standalone JavaScript interpreter (jslibs)?

Tags: javascript, runtime

I am working on a standalone JavaScript development runtime environment for using JavaScript as a general-purpose scripting language.

Currently I support the following libraries:
zlib, SQLite, FastCGI, NSPR (Netscape Portable Runtime), ODE (Open Dynamics Engine), libpng, libjpeg, librsvg, freetype, librsvg, SDL, libiconv, OpenGL, OpenAL, ogg vorbis, libTomCrypt, libffi (Foreign function interface).

Now I am looking for other useful libraries to bind to my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphical: wxWidgets, QT
Text Manipulation: GNU Aspell

Just google for popular libraries. Believe me, you'll find a plenty of them ;)

Answer (score 4):

Add data storage libraries (RMDB, flat files, XML) and some window libraries (QT)

Answer (score 4):

Here's some libraries I'd like to see (there may be some overlap):

- Cryptography: mcrypt, OpenSSL
- Compression: zlib, zip, tar, bzip
- Database: mysql, postgresql, sqlite, oracle, mssql, couch
- Text: ICU (i18n), unicode, aspell
- Image: libgd, libexif, freetype
- Mail: cclient or anything really
- Math: libbcmath, dcdflib + randlib (stats)
- Binary output: pslib, pdflib, libswf
- Misc: memcached, cURL, ftp, OpenLDAP, libsvn,GeoIP

Answer (score 3):

You should have a GUI toolkit

- GTK or Qt

Database connectivity

- MySQL and PostgreSQL client library
  bindings

A few others I'd like to see

- google protocol buffers
- libxml2 or some other xml library
- libpcap
- OpenLDAP client libraries

Comment: Note: The JavaScript engine I use (TraceMonkey) use E4X to manage XML.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of graphics stuff in there. How about cairo?

Comment: I already use cairo through the librsvg library.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely something to handle file paths, to abstract path separation characters, check file existence, size and so on (aka stat), file permissions and/or ACLs
Basically something like the Perl File:: modules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful:

- ImageMagick
- libpurple
- libavcodec